# Form communication over components

Tags: reactjs

i just started using React and Meteor. I want to create a flexible Form validation, but it is not clear how the communication would work.

Here mu starting point:

```
Form = React.createClass(
{
    onSubmit(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

    },
    render()
    {
    return (
      <form id="a" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      {this.props.children}
      </form>
    )
    }
});


Input = React.createClass(
{
    render()
    {
    return (
             <input type="text"/>
           )
    }
});

Button = React.createClass(
{
    render()
    {
    return (
             <button value="submit" />
           )
    }
});
```

and the layout like ( later with properties for id, and form submit method )

```
Input = React.createClass(
{
    render()
    {
    return (
             <Form>
               <Input />
               <Button />
             </Form>
           )
    }
});
```

But how is it possible to loop over all Input components and getting the volue of each field, do i need to loop over all child's and get the ref's tag ( this.refs.input -  )?

I want to validate each field an set back error messages ( over states and componentWillReceiveProps )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into a library like [tcomb-form](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form), which provides the validation you want, but also handles the form rendering and has a simple declarative model for defining what the form needs. I've also found it to be fairly customizable.